# Qt Creator - The selected build of GDB does not support Python scripting

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator

I use a cross-compiled Qt setup on a CentOS host. Developing Qt applications and executing them remotely on the Raspberry Pi works fine. But I got the following error when I try to debug the application:

[image]

I use the standard GDB from the official [Raspberry Pi toolchain](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) (`tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb`).

So what is wrong? Why does the GDB needs Python scripting when I use C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually build GDB from source, so you can configure it to include Python support:

First some dependencies:

```sh
yum install -y texinfo gcc gcc-c++ make python3-devel wget
```

Then build and install GDB itself:

```sh
target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
version=9.1

# Download and extract
cd /tmp
[ -e gdb-$version.tar.xz ] || wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-$version.tar.xz
rm -rf gdb-$version
tar xf gdb-$version.tar.xz
mkdir -p gdb-$version/build
cd gdb-$version/build

# Get the Python executable and library directory
[ -z "${PYTHON}" ] && export PYTHON=python3
PYTHON_LIBDIR=$("${PYTHON}" -c \
    "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))")

# Configure GDB
../configure \
    --prefix="$HOME/.local" \
    --target=$target \
    --with-python="${PYTHON}" \
    LDFLAGS="-L${PYTHON_LIBDIR}"

# Build and install GDB
make -j$(nproc)
make -C gdb install
```

GDB will be installed in `~/.local/bin`, so add it to your path if you haven't already.

Answer (score 4):

You can run this command in your terminal to install **gdb**

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

Comment: Only the minimal version of the GDB (gdb-minimal) was installed on my Debian. `sudo apt install gdb` was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I had the same problem with a fresh Qt install on a fresh debian install.

When I ran

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

...I noticed that *gdb-minimal* was removed and the full *gdb* was installed.

That fixed the python problem and Qt Creator runs gdb with no problems.